# How to find the memory regions of a process used for DMA

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, dma

In linux kernel, given a process and its virtual memory space, is there a way to find the memory regions that are mapped for DMA (Direct Memory Access)? Maybe from the flags of its vma_area_struct?

Thanks

Comment: try `dmesg` Virtual kernel memory layout: here you find DMA     : 0xffc00000 - 0xffe00000

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could find out which pages are locked.
But the fact that a page is locked does not necessarily imply that it is for DMA.
If the DMA mappings are created by your driver, it is much easier to implement a proper book keeping instead of looking for DMA regions after-the-fact.